# Draw image in triangle region iphone

Tags: iphone

I draw an triangle using these piece of code

```
CGPoint center;

center = CGPointMake(x1, x2);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, center.x, center.y);
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, y1, y2);
            break;
        case 1:
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, z1, z2);
            break;
        case 2:
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x1, x2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Now the triangle has drawn in my uiview.I have an image size should be (420*300).I want to load this image in the triangle region . (Not out of this triangle region).

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: why do you need the loop? Why not sequence the Line calls directly?

Comment: Can you tell me , How could i load image in the triangle region ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding the lines into the context call [`CGContextClip`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextClip) then draw your image ([`CGContextDrawImage`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextDrawImage)). Your image will be clipped by the path. You can then use the same path to draw the triangle as lines too, if you like.

You'll probably find that your image is upside down, so you may need to apply a transform before drawing it - something like:

[`CGContextTranslateCTM`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_114)`( context, 0, image.size.height );`